# How do I configure Jest to use ES5

Tags: jestjs, ecmascript-5

Google is failing me on this one. We have a set of plain JS files, which will be executed in a proprietary JS environment which is compliant to the ECMA-Script-262 Edition 5 (ECMAScript5). To make sure our scripts aren't using any features of newer ES versions, I'd like to configure Jest to run using 'ECMAScript5'. I can't seem to find any configuration for that.

How do I configure Jest to use ES5?

Comment: Maybe "Jest" is wrong, and I should be asking the about configuring "jsdom". The basic question still remains, though.

Comment: My current understanding is that Jest / jsdom will ultimately run in a Node JS (V8) environment, which has no means to toggle a ES version. The only viable approach is to use something like ESLint and set ecmaVersion=5 there.